# Change the Placeholder Text for the Find a file search box for document libraries' web parts

Tags: 2013, web-part, document-library

I'm trying to change the placeholder text that says `Find a file` in the search box that is part of Document Library web parts. I've looked through the html on the page and it doesn't seem to be in there, so I must be missing something.

I want to change it to something like `Ex: SMS12345`

[image: Picture of find a file]

**Update**:

The id of the input that is that item: `inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ4_lsinput`

running: `document.getElementById('inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ4_lsinput').placeholder`
in the console returns `""`

Setting it: `document.getElementById('inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ4_lsinput').placeholder = "test-test-test"` does not have the anticipated results. Sharepoint must be doing something else behind the scenes. Both pictures are *After* running these commands in console.

[image: After1]

Now I click on the input:

[image]

**Solution:**
The script that finally got everything working mostly as expected

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function () {
document.getElementById('inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ4_lsinput').placeholder ='Ex: SMS1234';
document.getElementById('inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ4_lsinput').value= 'Ex: SMS1234';
}, 800);//time to wait for in ms
</script>
```

A few notes: Sharepoint seems to not use the built-in placeholder functionality, it instead adds a value to the input with the text "Find a File".

So you can set the value of the input, and it renders correctly. However, when you click on the input, it clears this value and shows the placeholder value (default "") and when you click off of the input, it replaces the value back with "Find a File", erasing your javascript work.

On top of that, using something like window.onload or jquery's document.ready or document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded" don't fire late enough to have the input available to be set, the only way I could get it was to use a timeout to get the javascript to fire

Lastly, and this caused me some trouble, if you don't include the type in the script tag (`<script>` instead of `<script type="text/javascript">`) it will work in edit mode but the javascript will not run once the page is saved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it quite simply by including a little bit of JavaScript on the page.

Either add it through a script web part of save to a file and add the file through a content web part.

```
window.onload = function () { 
document.getElementById('inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ4_lsinput').placeholder = 'Ex: SMS12345';

document.getElementById('inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ4_lsinput').value= 'Ex: SMS12345';
}
```

Edit: I did a stupid and used Jquery and native JS at the same time. The above code is tested in chrome and Firefox and works as expected. In IE10 for some reason only the value set works.

```
window.onload = function () { 
  setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementById('inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ2_lsinput').placeholder ='Ex: SMS12345';

    document.getElementById('inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ2_lsinput').value= 'Ex: SMS12345';

  }, 1000);//time to wait for in ms
}
```

Looks like SP does stuff in a strange way. As a work around have the code set to run shorty after the page loads (in example it is 1 second). By having the code run shortly after page run there should be minimal loss of user experience as only a sharp eye would detect that the wording on a search bar has changed 1 second after the page loads.

Comment: So it seems that `document.ready` / `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded"` don't cut it here. The web part that is the document library doesn't load until after document.ready fires, I am able to replicate my console work by placing the placeholder setting code in a 3 sec timeout function, though that still doesn't give me good results (see question update)

Comment: You can use `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {` in place of jquery's `$(document).ready(function () {`

Comment: there are couple of techniques to avoid that here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16936250/sharepoint-2013-add-javascript-after-whole-page-load

Comment: @Aaron see updated code. Didn't get it to quite work properly on IE10 but the value set call works a pseudo placeholder in this instance (if you click on the search box it wipes the value)

Comment: @Roland The updated code works in the console, but I still can't get it to affect the other web part on the page without some sort of Timeout. I've tried using `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames` from Ahmed's link but it still won't resolve.

Comment: @Aaron Ah the page i tested it on had a lot of additional stuff that seems to have slowed the page down to enable the original code to work properly. I have added an update that sets it to shortly after page loads

Comment: So do I understand correctly that you can change its value and placeholder but cannot submit it using the text loaded from Javascript?

Comment: @JurgenCuschieri No any value that is in the search bar would be submitted however if you want to automatically search for something then the above would not be the way to do it. You are better off looking into the SharePoints Search API's

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Script Editor Web part on the page (and you can hide it from Script editor properties) and add a script tag to jQuery like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script> $( "#inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ1_lsparent :input").attr('placeholder','Ahmed'); </script>
```

Comment: How does this solve the issue above? Can you elaborate?

Comment: There is a problem with this code before we get to the issue at hand. The 2nd line of code will run before the input `inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ1_lsparent` has been created, so no effect.