# Doc library search box web part alter placeholder text

Tags: search-box

I'm trying to change the default text "Find a file" to something else.

Does anyone have a fix for this?

[This solution](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/179971/change-the-placeholder-text-for-the-find-a-file-search-box-for-document-librarie) only works up to a certain point.
When a user focuses in and out of the search box - placeholder text will default.

```
window.onload = function () { 
document.getElementById('inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ4_lsinput').placeholder = 'Ex: SMS12345';

document.getElementById('inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ4_lsinput').value= 'Ex: SMS12345';
}
```

or this..

```
window.onload = function () { 
  setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementById('inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ2_lsinput').placeholder ='Ex: SMS12345';

    document.getElementById('inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ2_lsinput').value= 'Ex: SMS12345';

  }, 1000);//time to wait for in ms
}
```

Is there really no complete solution for this issue?

Thanks

Comment: are you need to change the default find an item for a specific list ? also are you face issue in the above code ?

Comment: Yeah specific list. When the page loads the value I set indeed takes effect. However it's defaulting to "Find a file" when I focus in&out of the search box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should handle the `blur` event of the `input` element as below

```
var form = document.getElementById("inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ1_lsinput");
form.addEventListener("blur", function( event ) {
    if(event.target.value == "" || event.target.value == "Find a file"){
        event.target.value = "Ex: SMS12345";
    }     
}, true);
```

**Update**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    window.onload = function () {
        alert('Onload');
        document.getElementById('inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ4_lsinput').placeholder = 'Ex: SMS12345';
        document.getElementById('inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ4_lsinput').value= 'Ex: SMS12345';
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(startFunction, "sp.js");            
    } 
    function startFunction(){
        alert('Start Function');
        var form = document.getElementById("inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ1_lsinput"); 
        form.addEventListener("blur", function( event ) { 
            if(event.target.value == "" || event.target.value == "Find a file"){ 
                event.target.value = "Ex: SMS12345"; 
            } 
        }, true); 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Amal, the code you provided does not work for me. injected it in a Script web part with the correct id. Does not seem to do anything.

Comment: This should go inside the window.load function.. or better use ExecuteDelay that is recommended for SharePoint

Comment: can you please provide the full code that works.
I was trying this but it doesn't take.

    `<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () { 
var form = document.getElementById("inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ1_lsinput");
form.addEventListener("blur", function( event ) {
    if(event.target.value == "" || event.target.value == "Find a file"){
        event.target.value = "Ex: SMS12345";
    }     
}, true);
}
</script>`

Comment: @HoooooP sorry for the delay.. try my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the updated script.
I've noticed that your code only works for me once I focus into the searchbox with my mouse cursor (it works every time after that). If I don't focus into the field the placeholder text stays as default.
Do you have any idea how to overcome this ?

Comment: You should combine mine along with the script in your question

Comment: How so? 
Thank you

Comment: Updated answer.